# Split a Pandas Dataframe Row into Multiple columns while preserving other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am quite new to building my own code from scratch.  I'm able to read code to some level and appropriate what I find online, but I've not been able to find something that fits with my case and I would very much like to better my Python skills.

have a dataframe that takes the shape of:

| INDEX | PDATETIME | LOT | PROD | MEAS_TYPE | MEAS_AVG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-07-19 12:02:45 | Sample1 | EX | Meas1 | 30.7124 |
| 1 | 2021-07-19 12:02:45 | Sample1 | EX | Meas2 | 0.9992 |
| 2 | 2021-07-19 12:02:45 | Sample1 | EX | Meas3 | 0.3948 |
| 3 | 2021-07-19 12:03:45 | Sample2 | EX | Meas1 | 0.5185 |
| 4 | 2021-07-19 12:03:45 | Sample2 | EX | Meas2 | 0.2171 |
| 5 | 2021-07-19 12:03:45 | Sample2 | EX | Meas3 | 0.9885 |

I am looking to convert it to the following:

| INDEX | PDATETIME | LOT | PROD | MEAS1 | MEAS2 | MEAS3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-07-19 12:02:45 | Sample1 | EX | 30.7124 | 0.9992 | 0.3948 |
| 1 | 2021-07-19 12:03:45 | Sample2 | EX | 0.5185 | 0.2171 | 0.9885 |

I've tried using pivot, and it would work if I didn't have the additional columns (e.g. LOT, PROD).

Some additional things to consider: the number of samples present in LOT can be anywhere from 1 to over a million. The PROD isn't limited to a unique value (e.g. EX). MEAS_TYPE can contain anywhere from 1 to dozens of parameters.

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: `df.pivot(index=['PDATETIME', 'LOT', 'PROD'], columns='MEAS_TYPE', values='MEAS_AVG').reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)`

Comment: Yes it does! Thank you very much. I'll have to spend some time unpacking what you've done, but that will be good for me. :)

Comment: Columns you want to "save" go into the index. The column that has the labels for the new columns goes in "columns" and the values that should go under those new columns goes in "values".

Comment: More manually, you could do something like this `df.set_index(['PDATETIME', 'LOT', 'PROD', 'MEAS_TYPE']).drop(columns=['INDEX']).unstack()`